# (MATLAB) Can I re-plot imported data from axes in GUI to new figure using copyfile?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, figure

Hello I've made a GUI with a button to select a folder containing files and then plot them all on a single axes in the GUI.

I've also made a button so that if the user wants to open up this plot in new figure they can. However, for this button, they have to select the same folder again (all I did was include figure; axes; in the same code). But is there a way to save the data that was selected so that they don't have to choose the folder again? I'm thinking of using the copyfile function, but I have no idea how to do it...

Here is the code for the first button (import data):

```
d= uigetdir(pwd, 'Select a folder');

files = dir(fullfile(d, '*.txt'));

len = length(files);

linecolors = jet(len);

for i = 1:len

a = files(i).name;

filename{i} = a;

path = [d,'\',a];

data = dlmread(path);

plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),'color',linecolors(i,:),'linewidth',2);

hold on;

end

hold off;

xlabel('Intensity','fontweight','bold');

ylabel('Wave Number','fontweight','bold');

title('Spectra Plot','fontweight','bold','fontsize',14);

legend(filename,'Interpreter','none', 'location', 'southoutside');
```

Here is the code for the second button (open in new figure) with just 2 additional lines (5th and 6th line) :

```
d= uigetdir(pwd, 'Select a folder');

files = dir(fullfile(d, '*.txt'));

len = length(files);

linecolors = jet(len);

figure();

axes;

for i = 1:len

a = files(i).name;

filename{i} = a;

path = [d,'\',a];

data = dlmread(path);

plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),'color',linecolors(i,:),'linewidth',2);

hold on;

end

hold off;  

xlabel('Intensity','fontweight','bold');

ylabel('Wave Number','fontweight','bold');

title('Spectra Plot','fontweight','bold','fontsize',14);

legend(filename,'Interpreter','none', 'location', 'southoutside');
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Vera

Comment: I read your comment on the other answer, so i modified my answer. There is a faster way to do what you want. Check the top part of my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: now I read your comment on the other answer, there is a faster way to do what you want. The first answer explained how to save and retrieve values from different part of your gui, but all you need in your case is to do a copy of your axes in a new figure.

So another way to achieve that is :
Keep exactly the same code for button 1 (either my code or even your original code), then for button 2:

```
hfig = ancestor(gcbo,'figure') ;        %// find the handle of the current figure
hax = findobj( hfig , 'type', 'axes') ; %// find the handle of the axes inside the main figure
hfig2 = figure ;                        %// create a new figure
hax2  = copyobj(hax,hfig2);             %// make a full copy of the axes in the new figure
```

This way you do not have to re-read all your files and load the data.

---

*initial answer:*

You can save parameters or variables in the figure application data, using the [`setappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) commands.

In your case you can save the file list so you do not need to retrieve it again (this assume you will always use the button 1 first).

The function which actually plot can be separated, so you do not need to repeat the code. Just use the handle (the address) of the destination `axes` as a parameter.

So **Code for button 1**

```
%// get the folder location and list of files
d= uigetdir(pwd, 'Select a folder');
fileList = dir(fullfile(d, '*.txt'));

hfig = ancestor(gcbo,'figure') ;        %// find the handle of the current figure
hax = findobj( hfig , 'type', 'axes') ; %// find the handle of the axes inside the main figure

setappdata( hfig , 'fileList' , fileList ) ; %// save the file list in the figure application data

plot_files( fileList , hax ) %// call the ploting function, specifying the CURRENT axes as destination
```

**Code for button 2**

```
hfig = ancestor(gcbo,'figure') ;                %// find the handle of the current figure
fileList = getappdata( hfig , 'fileList' ) ;    %// retrieve the file list in the figure application data
hfig2 = figure ;                                %// create a new figure
hax2 = axes('Parent',hfig2) ;                   %// create an axes in the new figure
plot_files( fileList , hax2 ) %// call the ploting function, specifying the NEW axes as destination*
```

And somewhere at the end of your `.m` file, place the **plotting function**:

```
%% // Code for function to place somewhere at the bottom of your .m file
function plot_files( fileList , selectedAxe )
    len = length(files);
    linecolors = jet(len);

    for i = 1:len
        a = files(i).name;
        filename{i} = a;
        path = [d,'\',a];
        data = dlmread(path);
        plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),'color',linecolors(i,:),'linewidth',2,'Parent',selectedAxe );
        hold on;
    end

    hold off;
    xlabel('Intensity','fontweight','bold');
    ylabel('Wave Number','fontweight','bold');
    title('Spectra Plot','fontweight','bold','fontsize',14);
    legend(filename,'Interpreter','none', 'location', 'southoutside');
end
```

note: depending how your other functions are defined in the code you may have to remove the last `end` of the plotting function. (if all your functions finish with `end`, then keep this one, otherwise just remove it).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer just what I was looking for! I'm new to matlab (only been using it for a few days) so thanks for the detailed explanation of your method, it makes it easier for me to understand your coding, I'll give it a try now :)

Comment: @VeraM, If you use option 2 (initial answer), I forgot to specify `'Parent',selectedAxe` in the call to plot in the ploting function. It is corrected now but make sure you use the latest version ;-)

Comment: Ah thanks very much, I didn't know I could find such helpful people online! I will try out both methods and see which is best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use savefig command in Matlab to save the figure and the pressing of the button simply loading that figure.
Write

```
 savefig('figure1.fig')
```

at the end of the first bit of code. And just

```
openfig('figure1.fig','new')
```

in the second bit of code.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer :) your code does work and opens up an exact copy of the user interface, but I want the user to be able to open up just the plot and legend in a new figure window so that they can easily print/save it. Your method copies all the buttons in the GUI as well, and there isn't a menu option to print or save the figure. Can you think of any other way? Thanks for your previous answer as well, I do appreciate it!