# How to retrieve data from one gui to another gui in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have two GUIs. In the first gui I want to plot an input signal (ex: sine signal). My problem is, how can I plot back the same signal in the second GUI after I clicked the 'load' pushbutton in the second GUI? Can somebody help me? I really need help.

Comment: There are actually many many examples of how to do just that; if you Google the title of your question you will see that a good way to go is to use [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html?searchHighlight=getappdata).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I already google it and yes I found many solution but unfortunately I don't really quite understand the example. Can you help?

Comment: Yep sure! Are you building the GUIs with GUIDE?

Comment: Thanks, I really need help! Yes, I use GUIDE. I named my first GUI as 'sine_signal' (tag: gui_sine) and my second GUI as 'filtering' (tag: gui_filtering).

Comment: You probably want to read this: [What's the "right" way to organize GUI code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064610/whats-the-right-way-to-organize-gui-code)

Comment: And your question is very very similar to this one: [(MATLAB) Can I re-plot imported data from axes in GUI to new figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704239/matlab-can-i-re-plot-imported-data-from-axes-in-gui-to-new-figure-using-copyfi/), you should have a look at it and at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to get you going about using `setappdata` and `getappdata`. This is very basic and there are things which I did not mention (eg using the handles structure or passing variables as input arguments to functions) but using `setappdata` and `getappdata` is a safe way to go.

I created 2 programmatic GUIs. The code looks a bit different than when GUIs are designed with GUIDE, but the principle is exactly the same. Take the time to examine it and understand what everything does; that's not too complicated.

Each GUI is composed of one pushbutton and an axes. In the 1st GUI (`sine_signal`) the sine wave is created and displayed. Pressing the pushbutton opens the 2nd GUI (`gui_filtering`) and calls `setappdata`. Once you press the pushbutton of that 2nd GUI, `setappdata` is called to fetch the data and plot it.

Here is the code for both GUIs. You can save them as .m files and press "run"  in the `sine_signal` function.

**1)** sine_signal

```
function sine_signal

clear
clc

%// Create figure and uicontrols. Those will be created with GUIDE in your
%// case.
hFig_sine = figure('Position',[500 500 400 400],'Name','sine_signal');

axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .8]);

uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[10 370 120 20],'String','Open gui_filtering','Callback',@(s,e) Opengui_filt);

%// Create values and plot them.
xvalues = 1:100;
yvalues = sin(xvalues).*cos(xvalues);

plot(xvalues,yvalues);

%// Put the x and y values together in a single array.
AllValues = [xvalues;yvalues];

%// Use setappdata to associate "AllValues" with the root directory (0).
%// This way the variable is available from anywhere. You could also
%// associate the data with the GUI itself, using "hFig_sine" instead of "0".

setappdata(0,'AllValues',AllValues);

%// Callback of the pushbutton. In this case it is simply used to open the
%// 2nd GUI.

    function Opengui_filt

        gui_filtering

    end
end
```

And

**2)** gui_filtering

```
function gui_filtering

%// Same as 1st GUI.
figure('Position',[1000 1000 400 400],'Name','sine_signal')

axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .8])

%// Pushbutton to load data
uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[10 370 100 20],'String','Load/plot data','Callback',@(s,e) LoadData);

%// Callback of the pushbutton
    function LoadData

        %// Use "getappdata" to retrieve the variable "AllValues".

        AllValues = getappdata(0,'AllValues');

        %// Plot the data
        plot(AllValues(1,:),AllValues(2,:))        
    end
end
```

To show you the expected output, here are 3 screenshots obtained when:

1) You run the 1st GUI (`sine signal`):

[image]

2) After pressing the pushbutton to open the 2nd GUI:

[image]

3) After pressing the pushbutton of the 2nd GUI to load/display the data:

[image]

That's about it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Heyy thank you very much for your feedback and your help! I will study and try to understand the programming. I will let you know later on! :)